# Why can't I set input values when ng-model is used?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to populate some default fields in a form. The AngularJS way as far as I know is to use the controller to set these values. I'm using components - which I'm starting to regret given that most examples online don't use this layout.

**component.js**

```
angular.
  module('patientInfo').
  component('patientInfo', {
    templateUrl: 'patient-info/patient-info.template.html',
    controller: ['$http', '$routeParams',
      function PatientInfoController($http, $routeParams, $scope) {
        var self = this;
        this.patientId = $routeParams.patientId;

        $http.get("patients/" + this.patientId + ".json").then(function(response) {
          self.patient = response.data;
        });
      }
    ]
  });
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>{{$ctrl.patient[0].first_name}} {{$ctrl.patient[0].last_name}}</h1>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <!--Sidebar content-->
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-10">
    <!--Body content-->
    <form action="" >
      <p>First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="first_name"></p>
      <p>Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="last_name"></p>
      <p>Patient Date of Birth: <input type="text" ng-model="patient_dob" ></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to accomplish is to populate all those fields (name, dob) with elements from a JSON file. My problem is likely two-fold:

1. When I write `$scope.first_name = "anything"` I'm told `Cannot set property 'first_name' of undefined`. Why is this the case?
2. Assuming I figure out the first item, how would I go about using fields from the JSON file (self.patient or response.data)? Could I write: `$scope.first_name = self.patient[0].first_name`? My intuition is no, so what would be the proper way to both reference the JSON data inside my controller?

Bonus question: What are the idiosyncrasies that one should be aware of when using a component like this as opposed to the more traditional controller definition? I'm relatively new to web development and am finding myself overwhelmed by the number of ways to accomplish the same thing.

Sample response data would just be a JSON array with a single value:

```
[{"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "hospital_name": "Mayo Clinic","dob": "01/01/01"}]
```

Comment: Have you tried ` controller: ['$http', '$routeParams', '$scope',`

Comment: No because I'm a complete masochist. You've solved my first issue! Now how would I go about solving the second one because what I have listed definitely doesn't work.

Comment: could we see a sample of what `response.data` looks like? (you should be able to get this using `console.table(response.data)` or `console.dir(response.data)`)

Comment: When you use a component you don't typically use `$scope` because the component's controller is automatically instantiated with an identifier of `$ctrl`. You have used this in your template already, you just need to extend its use to the `ng-model` values as well. I would recommend changing `self.patient = response.data;` to `self.patient = response.data[0];`. That way you can use `$ctrl.patient` directly in your HTML instead of having to include an array index.

Comment: @JacobIRR I updated the question with a sample JSON item

Comment: If you remove `[0]` from `$ctrl.patient[0]` that should work

Comment: @Lex I'm not sure I follow. If I don't use `$scope`, what would be the proper way to change the fields from the component controller?

Comment: Instead of `ng-model="first_name"` it would be `ng-model="$ctrl.patient[0].first_name"` or `ng-model="$ctrl.patient.first_name"` if you follow my other suggestion above.

Comment: @JacobIRR My problem isn't on the template side. I need the `[0]` because it's technically a JSON array. I'm trying to figure out how to use the JSON data from the controller

Comment: Oh I see, in that case, you should do : `self.patient = response.data[0]` in the controller and then you won't need [0] in the HTML

Comment: @Lex on the money. You both solved both my issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as first question was answered in the comments, let's move to the second one.

The answer is YES, you can write it like:

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
$http.get("patients/" + this.patientId + ".json").then(function(response) {
        //this will copy all properties from response.data[0] into $scope
        Object.assign($scope, response.data[0]);
    });
```

And then you'll be able to see data into that fields after you get the request.
But sometimes the $digest cycle (angular.js thing that updated all the values in the html) is not reacting to async calls, so you could try to use this code

```js
angular.
  module('patientInfo').
  component('patientInfo', {
    templateUrl: 'patient-info/patient-info.template.html',
    controller: ['$http', '$routeParams', '$scope', '$timeout',
      function PatientInfoController($http, $routeParams, $scope, $timeout) {
        var self = this;
        this.patientId = $routeParams.patientId;

        $http.get("patients/" + this.patientId + ".json").then(function(response) {
          $timeout(function() {
            Object.assign($scope, response.data[0])
          });
        });
      }
    ]
  });
```

In the last snippet I've added the $timeout directive from angular that triggers the $digest cycle after the execution

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you have not taken `$scope` service in controller definition array

```
angular.
  module('patientInfo').
  component('patientInfo', {
    templateUrl: 'patient-info/patient-info.template.html',
    controller: ['$http', '$routeParams', '$scope', //This was missing
      function PatientInfoController($http, $routeParams, $scope) {
        var self = this;
        this.patientId = $routeParams.patientId;

        $http.get("patients/" + this.patientId + ".json").then(function(response) {
          self.patient = response.data;

          //Now you can write

          $scope.first_name = "anything"

        });
      }
    ]
  });
```